# How to search and match if a sheet name from a cell value in another sheet in google apps script and copy cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have three sheets, in the JOBS sheet if the user email address matches a sheet name in the QUOTATIONS workbook then the price is taken from that sheet for the specified product in column P. If no sheet name is found then the price for that product is taking from the PRODUCTS sheet. The price also depends on the currency which is specified in the JOBS sheet.
A sample of the expected results can be viewed in the JOBS sheet in column Q at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1up7cUvQqL-LcA7EeuM65B0zjcRT46LGwN2x3C_4j0bY/edit?usp=sharing
If the user has a quotation and the email matches a sheet name then the price comes from QUOTATIONS workbook at
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10tb0zE_8i849T-hL6mU-Pw_4V-aMzNZJGNOFYG1F3qk/edit?usp=sharing
If the user has no quotation and there is no matching email address the price comes from the products sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU/edit?usp=sharing

I have the following script which does match the price between the products sheet and the jobs sheet but unable to have it also check if a sheet name exists and it matches the email address in the jobs sheet and then gets the price from that sheet. Assistance is appreciated, thanks

```
function updateQuotationPrice() {
  
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobSheet = ss.getSheetByName('JOBS');
  var productSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU").getSheetByName('PRODUCTS');
  var quotationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("10tb0zE_8i849T-hL6mU-Pw_4V-aMzNZJGNOFYG1F3qk");
  var sheetNames = []
 var sheets = quotationSheet.getSheets()//.forEach(function(sheet){sheets[sheet.getName()]=sheet;});
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
    sheetNames.push(sheet.getName());
  console.log(sheets)
  });

  var objEuro = productSheet.getRange("A2:D" + productSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) =>  (o[r[0]] = r[3], o), {});
  var objSterling = productSheet.getRange("A2:D" + productSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) =>  (o[r[0]] = r[2], o), {});
  var objQuotationEuro = sheets.getRange("A2:D" + sheets.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) =>  (o[r[0]] = r[3], o), {}); 
  var objQuotationSterling = sheets.getRange("A2:D" + sheets.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((o, r) =>  (o[r[0]] = r[2], o), {});
  var range = jobSheet.getRange("O2:AK" + jobSheet.getLastRow());
  var euroValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objEuro[r[0]] || null]);
  var sterlingValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objSterling[r[0]] || null]);
  var quotationEuroValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objQuotationEuro[r[0]] || null]);
  var quotationSterlingValues = range.getValues().map(r => [objQuotationSterling[r[0]] || null]);
  var vs = jobSheet.getRange("O2:R"+ jobSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  vs.forEach((r) => {  
    
    if(r[0] == "EURO" && r[1].match(/^A/i) && sheets != r[3]  ){
  range.offset(0, 2, euroValues.length, 1).setValues(euroValues)};
  
  if(r[0] == "STERLING" && r[1].match(/^A/i)  && sheets != r[3]){
  range.offset(0, 2, sterlingValues.length, 1).setValues(sterlingValues)}
  
   if(r[0] == "EURO" && r[1].match(/^A/i) && sheets == r[3] ){
  range.offset(0, 2, quotationValues.length, 1).setValues(quotationEuroValues)}

  if(r[0] == "STERLING" && r[1].match(/^A/i) && sheets == r[3] ){
  range.offset(0, 2, quotationValues.length, 1).setValues(quotationSterlingValues)}
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Suggestion

I have created another approach wherein I still used the `forEach()` function to process the data. However, I used the `filter()` and `includes()` function to help in the data matching process.

### Script

You may use the following script as basis for your script.

```
function updateQuotationPrice() {
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("User Update Sheet ID"); //User Update
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Quotation Sheet ID"); //Quotation
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Projects Sheet ID"); //Projects

  //Extract data from User Update
  var lr1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Jobs").getLastRow();
  var data1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Jobs").getRange(2, 13, lr1 - 1, 4).getValues();

  //Extract data from Quotation Spreadsheet
  var sheetNames2 = [];
  ss2.getSheets().forEach(x => sheetNames2.push(x.getName()));

  //Process data 1
  var output = [];
  data1.forEach(x => {
    if (sheetNames2.includes(x[0]) && ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[3])).length > 0) { // added new condition here
      if (x[2] == "EURO") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[3]))[0][3]]);
      }
      else if (x[2] == "STERLING") {
        output.push([ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[3]))[0][2]]);
      }
    }
    else {
      if (x[2] == "EURO") {
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("Products").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[3]))[0][3]]);
      }
      else if (x[2] == "STERLING") {
        output.push([ss3.getSheetByName("Products").getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[3]))[0][2]]);
      }
    }
  });

  //Output
  ss1.getSheetByName("Jobs").getRange(2, 17, lr1 - 1, 1).setValues(output);
}
```

### Output

[image]

### References

- [forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have questions with respect to the posted answer.

Comment: Well constructed and efficient; my approach was virtually identical but my code was >100 lines; this is @60% shorter.

Comment: @PatrickdC, this is great! Works just as I asked. Thank you. For a modification, how could the script be edited so that if no product code is found in the QUOTATIONS sheet for the email address, then the price for that product is taken from the PRODUCTS sheet?

Comment: Added an additional conditional statement in the if statement `if (sheetNames2.includes(x[0]) && ss2.getSheetByName(x[0]).getDataRange().getValues().filter(y => y.includes(x[3])).length > 0)`

Comment: @PatrickdC, the additional if statement works perfect. Thank you

Comment: @PatrickdC, another issue I'm having is if a cell in x[10] is blank, I  added ```if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[10] != "")``` in the if condition, but the error I have is "The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 5 but the range has 6" Have you a solution on how to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize but I think that this already counts as another question since you have added `if (x[9] == "EURO" && x[10] != "")` wherein I am not familiar with the index you used. I recommend that you post it as another question so that I, as well as other community members, may look into the whole new code and analyze it. With respect to `The data has 5 but the range has 6`, I believe this pertains to the array size of the output data (which is 5) not matching the range of the placeholder of the output (which is 6). Adjusting the `getRange()` of the `setValues` line to 5 might help.